# Chart layout and bar labelling

Tags: r, layout, charts

Currently trying to create this [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlTuH.jpg).

Having some difficulty getting the graph in to box number 1.

Also not sure how to label within the bars, any help would be appreciated!
The code I have so far is

```
Subject =
  c("Humanities", "Social Sciences", "Science", "Economics", "Engineering", 
    "Construction", "Electrical Engineering", "Vehicles and Transport", 
    "Business Studies", "Industrial Engineering", "Agriculture", 
    "Nursing (Care)", "Catering", "Nursing")
Female =
  c(85, 71, 52, 56, 19, 1, 4, 4, 62, 3, 50, 87, 58, 92)
Area =
  c("Theory", "Theory", "Theory", "Theory", "Theory", "Vocational", 
    "Vocational", "Vocational", "Vocational", "Vocational", "Vocational", 
    "Vocational", "Vocational", "Vocational")
Male = 100 - Female

Data = data.frame (Subject = Subject, Area = Area, 
                     Female = Female, Male = Male)
orderFemale = order (Data$Female)
Gender1991 = Data[orderFemale, ]
head (Gender1991)

##Create a plotting layout. Check with layout.show then remove
layout (matrix (c (0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 5, 5, 0,
               0, 4, 3, 0,
               0, 2, 1, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 0),
            nc = 4, byrow = TRUE),
    widths = c (lcm(1), 1, 1, lcm(1)),
    heights = c (lcm(1), lcm(1), lcm (1),
                 1, lcm(1)))
layout.show (5)
par (mar = rep (0, 4))

xlim = c (0, 100)
ylim = c (0, length (Gender1991$Female))
yt = 1:length (Gender1991$Female)
yb = yt - 1

##Female data plotting
plot.new()
plot.window (xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
rect (0, yb, Gender1991$Female, yt)
axis (1)
axis (3)
box()

##Male data plotting
plot.new()
plot.window (xlim = rev(xlim), ylim = ylim, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
rect (0, yb, Gender1991$Male, yt)
axis (1)
axis (3)
box()

label.panel = 
  function (label, xadj = .5, yadj = .5, cex = 1,
        font = 1, col = "black", angle = 0){
plot.new()
plot.window (xlim = c (0, 1), ylim = c (0, 1), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
text (xadj, yadj, label, font = font, cex = cex, col = col,
      adj = c (xadj, yadj), srt = angle)
  }

genderLabel = c ("Number of girls", "Number of boys")
heading = "Intake by sex into three-year courses at upper secondary school 1991"

label.panel (genderLabel[1], xadj = 1)
label.panel (genderLabel[2], xadj = 0)
label.panel (heading, font = 2)
```

But this code currently makes the graph take up the whole area and has a few other formatting issues.
Would really appreciate some advice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure hope to help with most of this, but
I noticed that on the graph the axis are marked at 25, 50, 75 and 100.

To adjust yours to match this is what you can do

```
##Female data plotting
plot.new()
plot.window (xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
rect (0, yb, Gender1991$Female, yt)
axis (1)
axis (3)
box()
```

In each of the axis () change to 
    axis (1, at=Dash)
Where dash is a vector of (0, 25, 50, 75, 100)

Hope this helps